# Make browser open new windows with SW_HIDE style?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, browser, hide, hidden

**Hello,**

- I want somehow to force the Firefox OR Chrome browser to open the browser windows **hidden** ( the windows to have the SW_HIDE style from the start when they are created ).

**For example :**
  *If I want to open a new browser window besides my current one, the browser to create a new window, but I to not even notice something has happened on the screen, because that new browser window was created hidden !*

I operate on Windows 7 and I program in AutoIT since Im beginner but I don't want any full source codes, I just want some advice on how to accomplish this.

For who doesn't know : SW_HIDE is a 'style' or 'property' that can be applied to any control/window/GUI to make it disappear from the screen, but to still exist and can be seen only in taskmanager.

**What I have tried :**
I could make a program to search in a loop for any new windows that are created by the browser process, and when finds  one, to quickly apply the SW_HIDE style to it, to disappear. But the problem is that this method is not fast enough, since I can still observe that new window for a sec and I loose the window and keyboard focus too. So the only solution would be to 'hack' the browser to make it open any new windows with the 'SW_HIDE' style, instead of 'SW_ACTIVE' style.

**Thankyou so much for any help!, and please if I was misleading post any question, I will respond very fast.Thankyou!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own patched version of chromium.

In the chromium Each new Window is created by code like this one:

```
#include "chrome/browser/ui/browser.h"
#include "chrome/browser/ui/browser_window.h"
#include "content/public/browser/navigation_controller.h"

Browser* CreateBrowser(Profile* profile) {
  Browser::CreateParams browser_params(Browser::TYPE_TABBED
      profile,
      chrome::HOST_DESKTOP_TYPE_FIRST);
  browser_params.initial_show_state = ui::SHOW_STATE_NORMAL;
  Browser* browser = new Browser(browser_params);
  browser->window()->Show();
  return browser;
}

// Simplified types definitions:
// class Profile;
//
// namespace ui {
//
// enum WindowShowState {
//   SHOW_STATE_DEFAULT    = 0,
//   SHOW_STATE_NORMAL     = 1,
//   SHOW_STATE_MINIMIZED  = 2,
//   SHOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED  = 3,
//   SHOW_STATE_INACTIVE   = 4,
//   SHOW_STATE_FULLSCREEN = 5,
//   SHOW_STATE_DETACHED   = 6,
//   SHOW_STATE_END        = 7
// };
//
// }  // namespace ui
//
// namespace chrome {
//
// enum HostDestkopType {
//   HOST_DESKTOP_TYPE_FIRST = 0,
//   HOST_DESKTOP_TYPE_NATIVE = HOST_DESTKOP_TYPE_FIRST,
// #if defined(OS_CHROMEOS)
//   HOST_DESKTOP_TYPE_ASH = HOST_DESKTOP_TYPE_NATIVE,
// #else
//   HOST_DESKTOP_TYPE_ASH,
// #endif
//   HOST_DESKTOP_TYPE_COUNT
// };
//
// }  // namespace chrome
//
// class Browser {
//  public:
//   enum Type {
//     TYPE_TABBED,
//     TYPE_POPUP
//   };
//   struct CreateParams {
//     CreateParams(Profile* profile, chrome::HostDesktopType host_desktop_type);
//     CreateParams(Type type, Profile* profile, chrome::HostDesktopType host_desktop_type);
//     static CreateParams CreateForApp(Type type, const std::string& app_name,
//         const gfx::Rect& window_bounds, Profile* profile,
//         chrome::HostDesktopType host_desktop_type);
//     static CreateParams CreateForDevTools(Profile* profile,
//         chrome::HostDesktopType host_desktop_type);
//     Type type;
//     Profile* profile;
//     chrome::HostDesktopType host_desktop_type;
//     std::string app_name;
//     gfx::Rect initial_bounds;
//     ui::WindowShowState initial_show_state;
//     bool is_session_restore;
//     BrowserWindow* window;
//   };
//
// explicit Browser(CreateParams params);
// BrowserWindow* window() const;
// };
```

You need to:

- checkout chromium sources (http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code).
- find `new Browser(` in the code and set `params.initial_show_state` to the `SHOW_STATE_MINIMIZED`
  in the case you want.
- build it (http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows).

Comment: Sounds plausible ! I will start working right now ! One question tho, if I will build it like you say, will it work even for pop-up windows created by the browser ?

Comment: How hard is to build it like you said ?

Comment: It takes much time but it's really easy to do. I working on chromium-based browser and I build it several times a day.